# How to disable webview sleep in ionicframework

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, webview, wakelock

In an application using ionicframework and vue js, I am using websockets to communicate with the server. As long as the screen is lit, the connection is active, messages arrive. After the screen is turned off, webview goes to sleep, messages from the server stop arriving.

I know I can disable the screensaver, but it drains the battery faster.

Is it possible to prevent webview from sleeping when screen is off when using ionicframework?

Comment: No, not possible.